# Creating multiple dlls for each web page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

The way we have to update our site now is to create a copy of the website project locally. Make changes. Then take the dll and any other new files and copy them to the project on the server. Sometimes they want us to work on something they need uploaded right away and other times work on something that needs to be uploaded in the future. So I have to do silly things to give them what they want now and exclude what I am working on for later. What is the best way to resolve this? I just wanna have to upload a piece of the project and certainly not the a whole new dll everytime.

Comment: IS THERE ANYWAY TO DO THIS WITHOUT A SOURCE CONTROL OPTION? They dont think source control is nessarry since only one person is working on the project.

Comment: I understand your bind (time/resources/etc).  But that "only one person" is not the issue here.  The issue is keeping your development branch and production branch separate.  I don't recommend this but you could do a 'poor man's' source control and keep two different code folders (dev and prod) on your machine and move files between them.  Just keep in mind it is more prone to human error and has no rollback capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source control w/ branching.  Then you can keep the production branch clean while you work on your future enhancements. There are plenty of great free source control tools, see below.

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

Comment: Plus, you might want to consider versioning your DLLs (1.0.0.0 or 1.3.0.1342). Make sure you can track back from a DLL version number to a revision in your repo, e.g. by including the revision number in your DLL version number. Probably best to automate this process using MSBuild or another build tool.

Comment: What will versioning the dlls do? They are not versioned now

Comment: @Nick - They'll help you be able to tell which versions are actually on the production box instead of having to guess. If every assembly is marked version "1.0.0.0" there could be confusion on what is actually deployed. see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx